# Is it possible to index custom page content?

Tags: search

I have created certain pages and blocks using web services programmatically.The content of those pages is fetched from outside the existing Drupal installation and they are not getting indexed in search results.

Is it possible to index my custom page titles and links in the search results? Or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: These custom pages you mention: are they nodes?

Comment: not nodes,
for example, 
I am displaying camps and events from our group website through web services programmatically with the help of hook_menu, drupal_http_request and so on.

I am not creating any any nodes of those contents, just showing it.

Comment: Well technically you can index custom contents. Node module and user module invoke search module (not the other way around). Node module is particularly a great example.

Comment: How?
any code example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can. You can use the [hook_node_update_index()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update_index/7.x) for this:

```
function YOURMODULE_node_update_index($node) {
   // here is an example that fetches content from an url and appends it to
   // to the data that will be indexed
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURL_URL, "http://example.com/readme.txt");
   $content = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);

   // return the extra content that needs to be indexed for this node
   return $content;
}
```

The above will of course only work if your custom pages are stored as nodes in Drupal. For instance if you have a node that is called `contact` which shows content generated externally, then you need to fetch the same content in `hook_node_update_index()` for this specific node.